# Virtual Environment is not being created in my User Account

Tags: python, django, windows, command-line, environment-variables

I recently created a new user on my family Laptop, so that I can have a seperate place for my django project.
I was trying to create a virtual environment, with the code :

```
C:\Users\Me\Desktop>python.exe -m venv themanor
```

it is not being created.
**But when I try the same code in the original Family User Account in my Windows, then it is being properly executed and I can see a new venv called 'themanor'.**
I tried changing my user from ***Standard to Administrator***, but it didn't help.

Please help, what settings do I need to change?.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: try ```pyhton -m virtualenv venv```

Comment: Make sure you have both- python and virtual env installed in the new account.

Comment: Yes it says - Access denied and later a pop up says that this app cannot run on your pc, to find a version for your pc check with a software publisher...

Answer (score 0):

`venv` will create the environment in the current directory of your terminal. It may have created it in your Desktop directory: `C:\Users\Me\Desktop\themanor`. If you are getting an error, Python may not be installed for all users. Not enough information was given to properly troubleshoot this.

Comment: I cant see it on the desktop, its definitely not being created, python 3.8.5 , same version  is installed for both users. What other info would help to troubleshoot this?,  I desperately want to solve this issue :(

Comment: error : Access denied and later a pop up says that this app cannot run on your pc, to find a version for your pc check with a software publisher.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, i was trying to execute the wrong code ( which weirdly worked on my admin user)
instead of :-

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>python.exe -m venv themanor
```

it should be

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop>py.exe -m venv themanor
```

***I still dont know*** why there is this inconsitency with cmd codes, but yeah, if u know hmu.

Comment: Check `where.exe python` to see what `python` runs.